# Logitech Help Hotkey active or Disable Script

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I'm new to the community and I'm a little lost as to how to resolve this issue. The idea is the following, there are 2 commands. I wanted to know how I can activate each of them separately using mouse button 4 and mouse button 5. Example, Tapping Mouse Button 4 activated the 1 command. I tapped Mouse button 5 disabled 4 and enabled 5. How can I be doing this:?

PS Logitech GHub Script

```
--test 
function OnEvent(event, arg)
      if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
          EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
      end
--test
-- Mouse Bind Keys --

local heavy = 4
local heavy2 = 5
 if IsKeyLockOn("Capslock")then
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1)then
      if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
      repeat
      MoveMouseRelative(0, 50) -- x and y axis
      Sleep(24)
      MoveMouseRelative(0, 50) -- x and y axis
      Sleep(24)
      MoveMouseRelative(0, 43) -- x and y axis
      Sleep(24)
      MoveMouseRelative(0, 28) -- x and y axis
      Sleep(24)
      MoveMouseRelative(15, -15) -- x and y axis
      Sleep(24)
      MoveMouseRelative(-15, 15) -- x and y axis
      Sleep(24)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
      end
    end
  end
 if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1)then
      if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
      repeat
      MoveMouseRelative(-16, 16) -- x and y axis
      Sleep(10)
      MoveMouseRelative(16, -16) -- x and y axis
      Sleep(10)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
      end
    end
  end 
end
--test
```

I searched in some forums but I didn't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Use variable `mode` for storing the most recent mode button (4,5) pressed.

```
local mode = 4

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
       EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and (arg == 4 or arg == 5) then
      mode = arg
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsKeyLockOn("Capslock") and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
      repeat
         if mode == 4 then
            MoveMouseRelative(0, 50) -- x and y axis
            Sleep(24)
            MoveMouseRelative(0, 50) -- x and y axis
            Sleep(24)
            MoveMouseRelative(0, 43) -- x and y axis
            Sleep(24)
            MoveMouseRelative(0, 28) -- x and y axis
            Sleep(24)
            MoveMouseRelative(15, -15) -- x and y axis
            Sleep(24)
            MoveMouseRelative(-15, 15) -- x and y axis
            Sleep(24)
         elseif mode == 5 then 
            MoveMouseRelative(-16, 16) -- x and y axis
            Sleep(10)
            MoveMouseRelative(16, -16) -- x and y axis
            Sleep(10)
         end
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
   end
end
```

Comment: Ours worked perfectly thank you very much. Taking advantage of the Topic, I have a Logitech Keyboard, if I wanted to change from Mouse 4 and 5 to F1 for example, would I need to change the MODE only and add F1?

Comment: To replace mouse button #4 with keyboard key `F1`: `if event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then mode = 4 end`

Comment: So I tried to switch to the F1 key (instead of Mouse 4) and F2 (instead of Mouse 5) and it didn't work, I think I did something wrong. I modified the Mouse_pressed part to G_Pressed and it didn't work, could you explain me better how this part would look?

Comment: To make `G_PRESSED` events generated, you must change standard bindings of `F1` and `F2` keys to some non-standard macros.  For example, to preserve standard function of `F1` key, just create your own macro "press F1 - wait 50ms - Release F1" and assign it to physical `F1` key.